# How to Initialize a random number generator within an array to use for a bubble sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So for my coding class, i was asked to create a bubble sort method that would take an array that would generate random numbers into the array, and sort them via bubble. I cant seem to get the Array to initialize. problem occurs within the for loop. Help please? The bubble works perfectly fine when i use pre-initialized numbers. Ignore the print statements.

[image: random int array method(Failure)]

Comment: No screenshots of code, please.  Copy/paste the actual text and format as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 28, you don't declare the type `int`. It's already been initialized when the array was created. Just use `randomNumbers[k] = (int)(Math.random()*10);`

Also, I used `randomNumbers` instead of `Array` for a reason. Don't use `Array` with a capital letter. That is a class name, not a variable. (Worse yet, it's a class that [exists already](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).)

Comment: Any particular reason for a down-vote? If I'm wrong about something, please leave a comment so I can correct/clarify it.

Comment: thanks, for some reason my other codes worked with Array, its really wierd

Comment: `Array` isn't a bug, so much as bad style. It's the `int` part that's the bug.